# How can I speed up this sapply for cross checking samples?

Tags: r, plyr

I'm trying to speed up a QC function for checking similarity between samples.  I wanted to know if there is a faster way to compare the way I am doing below?  I know there have been answers to this kind of question that are pretty definitive (on SO or otherwise) but I can't find them.  I know I should investigate `plyr` but I'm still getting a hold of `sapply`.

The following sample data is a representative output of what I would be working but randomized and I don't think would impact the application to my original question.

```
## sample data 
nSamples <- 1000
nSamplesQC <- 100
nAssays <- 96
microarrayScores   <- matrix(sample(c("G:G", "T:G", "T:T", NA),nSamples * nAssays,replace = TRUE), nrow = nSamples, ncol = nAssays) 
microarrayScoresQC <- matrix(sample(c("G:G", "T:G", "T:T", NA),nSamples * nAssays,replace = TRUE), nrow = nSamples, ncol = nAssays)
mycombs <- data.frame(Experiment = rep(1:nSamples,nSamplesQC),QC = sort(rep(1:nSamplesQC,nSamples)))

## testing function
system.time(
sapply(seq(length(mycombs[,1])), function(x) {compare <- microarrayScores[mycombs[x,1],]==microarrayScoresQC[mycombs[x,2],];
                                              sum(compare[!is.na(compare)])/sum(!is.na(compare))})
)
```

Comment: can you provide `chipScores` and `chipScoresQC`?

Comment: edited. It should have said `microarrayScores` and `microarrayScoresQC`.

Comment: One more question: are you sure you meant to compare the _rows_ of microarrayScores, rather than the columns?

Comment: @joran Yes.  I am interested in comparing the similarity of samples across assays.  If I did columns it might be useful too but not my intention at the moment.

Comment: Ok, the reason it's confusing is that you're looping over combinations of indicies from 1:96, which lines up with the number of columns, but it much smaller than the total number of rows.

Comment: @joran. I'm sorry. I must have copied the wrong version.  I changed it to represent what I was going for. Sigh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a vectorized version of your code, about 20 times faster on my machine:

```
rowMeans(microarrayScores[mycombs[,1], ] ==
         microarrayScoresQC[mycombs[,2], ], na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
foo <- function(x){
    compare <- microarrayScores[x[1],]==microarrayScoresQC[x[2],]
    sum(compare[!is.na(compare)])/sum(!is.na(compare))
}

system.time(apply(mycombs,1,foo))
```

appears to be modestly faster. (Maybe 2-3x)

Comment: Thanks for putting up with the confusion joran.  Do you have any resource on learning why this is faster?

Comment: @cyclondude I was just puzzling over the "Why" myself. Specifically, I was pondering if maybe `[` is faster working on the much smaller two element vector `x` in `foo` than the much larger matrix `mycombs`. It could also be some differences between `sapply` and `apply` that make the latter somewhat better suited to this particular case.

Comment: @cyclondude Also, I wouldn't accept my answer so quickly. Wait a little while and you may entice a few other people to work on this that might come up with something significantly better. I only sunk a few minutes of effort into it.

Comment: Do you think I should put it as a new question on SO?

Comment: @cyclondude No, I'll ask in the chat room about the performance difference and probably someone will weigh in.